# Express Async - Can't set headers after they are sent, double callback?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, express, callback

I'm having an annoying as hell problem with 'Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.' in Express. This code originally worked using Restify rather than Express and I have been having this problem in one form or another since converting it.

The code makes 2 asynchronous requests to another API (edited out) and merges the results into a single JSON before storing it in MongoDB.

Any insight would be appreciated as I have tried all I can think of and have no idea why the same function would work in Restify and not Express with the appropriate changes.

Please don't comment on the Pyramid of Doom, I know it's not ideal, but that's not the focus here ;)

```
app.post('/rest/test', jsonParser, /*keycloak.protect(),*/ function (req, res, next) {
var requestObj = req.body;

try {
    /* run async requests in parallel */
    async.parallel([
        function asyncReqV3(callback) {
            request.post(reqUrl1, option_v3, function(err, response, body) {
                if(err) {
                    console.log(err);   
                    callback(true);     
                    return;
                } else {
                    callback(false, body);
                }
            });
        },
        /* v4 async request */
        function asyncReqV4(callback) {
            request.post(reqUrl2, option_v4, function(err, response, body) {
                if(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    callback(true);
                    return;
                } else {
                    callback(false, body);
                }
            });
        },
    ],
    /* Collate results and send */
    function collateResults(err, results) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.status(500).send("Server Error");
        } else {
            /* Merging results */
            var hash = new Map();
            results[0].body.krResult.forEach(function(obj) {
                hash.set(obj.word, obj);
            });
            var final = results[1].body.data.map(function(obj) {
                return Object.assign(hash.get(obj.word) || {}, obj);
            });

            var final_results = final.slice(0, 250).map(function(obj) {
                return {
                    thing1: obj.something,
                    thing2: obj.somethingElse
                }
            });

            /* Store results in DB */
            db.results.insert({
                request: requestObj,
                response: final_results
            });

            res.status(200).send(final_results);
        }
    });
}
catch(e) {
   console.log(e);
   res.status(500).send({});
} 

return next();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of your route callback, remove:

```
return next();
```

You don't need it here and this line will always be executed before the `async.parallel` is done (`collateResults` in your code). You're quite likely sending a response in the subsequent routes and then again after your two requests are done.

Comment: This does indeed solve the problem. Weirdly I did this at several points before and got problems like empty reply from server, but no such issue today. Must have changed something else. Thanks a lot!